# Why does ($\lambda$c.x) $\lambda$e.f simplify to x?

Tags: lambda-calculus

Why does ($\lambda$*c.x*) $\lambda$*e.f* simplify to *x*?

The next step in this reduction I thought was to replace all c's with *x*. But there are no c's. What happens with the $\lambda$*e.f*?

I have gotten it from this [example on YouTube](https://youtu.be/3VQ382QG-y4?t=645), which I could follow, up to this point.

Comment: To reduce this, you replace all the $c$s in $x$ with $\lambda e.f$. But since there are no $c$s, all you're left with is $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $\lambda c.x$ is just a function that returns $x$ *no matter what the input is*. When you write:

$$ (\lambda c.x)(\lambda e.f) $$

What you should be doing is *substituting all the $c$'s in the expression $x$ with $(\lambda e.f)$*. Since there are no $c$'s in the expression $x$, the result of the substitution $x[c:= (\lambda e.f)]$ is simply $x$.

In a lambda-expression $\lambda x.(y)$, you should view $x$ as the parameter of the anonymous function and $y$ as the body, in which to perform the substitutions. For any further clarification I'll be available in the comments.

Comment: Great! Thank you. I'll chew on this for a bit.